# Java selenium getScreenshotAs ubuntu stack

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu

So I have this function that capture `screenshot` in case of test failure:

```
public static String captureScreenshot(String testName) throws IOException {
     File screenshotFile = takesScreenshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
     String path = "./screenshots/" + testName + ".png";
     FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, new File(path));
     return path;
}
```

So this work fine on `Windows` but on `Ubuntu` it seems that there is some deadlock or it is stuck at the first line of the method.

I try over and  over, wait even several minutes and nothing happened, it just stuck.

Comment: hey did you manage to resolve the problem???